# jquery - textbox not being read

Tags: jquery, autosuggest

I am trying to make the basics of an autosuggest searchbox for multiple textbox's. I already have a script to add/remvoe textboxes, which is working fine. But the problem I am having is being able to get all the textboxes on the page, when a key is done being pressed (onkeyup basically), it will alert the value of the textbox. I was able to get this to work for textboxes that I added my self in html, but any that are added using jquery never work.

here is the jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $counter = 0; // initialize 0 for limitting textboxes
    $('#buttonadd').click(function(){
        if ($counter < 10)
        {
            $counter++;
            $('#buttondiv').append('<div><label>Textbox #'+$counter+'</label><input type="text" name="textbox[]" class="textbox" value="" id="country"/></div>');
        }else{
            alert('You cannot add more than 10 textboxes');
        }
    });

    $('#buttonremove').click(function(){
        if ($counter){
            $counter--;
            $('#buttondiv .textbox:last').parent().remove(); // get the last textbox and parent for deleting the whole div
        }else{
            alert('No More textbox to remove');
        }
    });

    $('#buttonget').click(function(){
        alert($('.textbox').serialize()); // use serialize to get the value of textbox
    });

    $('input').bind('keyup', function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });

    $('#dropdownadd').change(function(){
        $('#dropdowndiv').html(""); // when the dropdown change set the div to empty
        $loopcount = $(this).val(); // get the selected value
        for (var i = 1; i <= $loopcount; i++)
        {
            $('#dropdowndiv').append('<div><label>Textbox #'+i+'</label><input type="text" name="textbox2[]" class="textbox2" value="" /></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

here is the html:

```
<div id="buttondiv">
<!-- this is where textbox will appear -->
</div>
<div class="choices">
    <span>Adding Textbox using Button</span>
    <input type="button" id="buttonadd" value="Add Textbox"/>
    <input type="button" id="buttonremove" value="Remove Textbox"/>
    <input type="button" id="buttonget" value="Get Textbox" />
</div>

<input id="country" size="25" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the binding function for keyup is called before the textbox's are generated. So either run the binding code(below) every time you create a new textbox.

```
$('input').bind('keyup', function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
```

or better way would be to use plain JavaScript onkeyup attribute to call a function that you have defined.
e.g.

```
$('#buttondiv').append('<div><label>Textbox #'+$counter+'</label><input type="text" name="textbox[]" class="textbox" onkeyup="function_abc(this);" value="" id="country"/></div>');
```

Comment: using onkeyup was the first thing I tried a while ago, but for some reason it worked this time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `on` instead of `click`

http://api.jquery.com/on/

This should work on dynamically added elements via delegation. I added a div to wrap the elements, both added manually and dynamically, then you can apply this

```
$('#container').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

See this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MGy5U/)